# Updating a value in a table using an identifier from another table (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this small table that I extracted from two tables
using this code:

```
select doctor_id, spec_code from doctor_speciality where doctor_id in 
(select doctor_id from doctor where doctor_fname='Decca' and doctor_lname=INITCAP('BLANKHORN'))
```

[image]

I am trying to use the value spec_code='THORAC' only to update a value in a third table. How can I achieve that?

This is the code I tried but it is not working.

My code:

```
Update speciality 
set spec_description='Vascular surgery' 
where spec_code='THORAC' in(
(select doctor_id, spec_code from doctor_speciality where doctor_id in 
(select doctor_id from doctor where doctor_fname='Decca' and doctor_lname=INITCAP('BLANKHORN'))));
```

Thanks

Comment: Which [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: SQL developer..

Comment: `spec_code="THORAC" in` ? What in what?

Comment: the code that creates the small table

Comment: @sue SQL Developer is a client tool. I was asking what RDBMS you are connecting to (e.g., MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS SQL Server, etc)

Comment: I don't know sorry

Comment: Sorry, I misread your request. Does the table speciality contain a spec_code? What are the tables' keys? It's doctor_id for doctor I guess, doctor_id + spec_code for doctor_speciality and spec_code for speciality? And you only want to update the speciality for THORAC, if doctor Decca Blackhorn has this spec? Or what else is the requirement?

Comment: Another question the answer to which may help us understand what you want to achieve: The query results in three spec codes. How do you know it's THORAC you want to work with and not OPHTA or RADIOL?

Comment: that is correct I know it is THORAC after I extracted the data. I want to update the value of spec_description that is identified by "THORAC".

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the requirement. And you have only answered parts of my questions. Let's imagine you didn't run the query. You didn't see that you get doctor_id 1060 and spec codes OPHTA, RADIAC, and THORAC. How would you describe the task?